# Jquery contact form to send mail to admin

Tags: jquery, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I'm propably going to need to use some form of Ajax here. But i'm pretty new to the Ajax usage withing Wordpress.

It is about the following. I have a Wordpress contact form that uses Bootstrap Validator and some Javascript to have a nice feel to it. I used the contact from from codepen and i made a Fork with my adjustments :

**Since i want to share the whole code around this i link the Fork with the functions and everything :**

[My Fork on the contact form](https://codepen.io/swatbe/pen/ybeMzE)

**The thing is that the contact form works fine but i can not figure out how to use wp_mail() in this to send a mail to the administrator since i use javascript and not PHP.**

Hope you guys can help me out with this one.

**UPDATE**

The ajax works! Thanks for the documentation. Now i seem to have another problem though. So i have certain input fields 'first_name' etc etc. But those are not reflecting in my email. Its all blank.

```
    function my_user_mailsend() {
    $message= $_POST['comment'];
    $contactname= $_POST['first_name'];
    $contactlastname= $_POST['last_name'];
    $contactemail = $_POST['email'];
    $headers = 'From: ' . $contactname . ' ' . $contactlastname . ' <' .$contactemail . '>' ;
    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

wp_mail( $to, $message, $headers );
    wp_die();
}

function my_nonuser_mailsend() {

    $contactname= $_POST['first_name'];
    $contactlastname= $_POST['last_name'];
    $contactemail = $_POST['email'];

    $headers = 'From: ' . $contactname . ' ' . $contactlastname . ' <' .$contactemail . '>' ;
    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
    $message= $_POST['comment'];

    wp_mail( $to, $message, $headers );
    wp_die();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without php you can't send an email. So as per your reference you have to use ajax and php.

In wordpress ajax is little bit different as compared to normal ajax. You can check the link for how to use ajax in wordpress.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/?utm_expid=3606929-101.TxEXoCfwS1KxJG1JVvj_5Q.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress-a-real-world-example/

Once you call the action inside ajax, in that action you can write your wp_mail.

Let me know if still you are not getting this.

Comment: I'm going to read all of this and try to figure it out :D Thanks for the documentation already.

Comment: I did all the research and i got it to work. Thanks! Now i seem to have another problem as my $_post are not working

Comment: regarding that you can ask question in another post

Comment: Got that also to work. I didn't parse the data trough ajax. Only the question to fire the function.